How to achieve react onchange event in angular with ngModelChange
html:
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"class="inputBox">
   <input matInput name="total" placeholder="0.00" [ngModel]="total"
     (ngModelChange)="handleOnChange('total', $event)" />
          </mat-form-field>

TS:
public handleOnChange = (field, e) => {
        console.log("hell", field)
        this.total=90
    }

the value of this.total should remain constant at 90 after any change event triggers the handleOnChange method and 90 should be appear as value in the input box constantly.This is the logic I am trying to achieve, but when there is a onChange at first time, value of input is changed to 90 but after first time when any key is pressed,value is changed. eg. 90a, 90tyhuil, 90oojh....
i come from react. how to achieve the onChange event in input tag of react in angular?

Nothing prevents you from handling onchange seperately: <input (change)="doSomething($event)" [ngModel]="someValue">

We can just pass the input field directly to function and set the value to the desired result, this will override any changes!
html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>

  <input
    matInput
    name="total"
    placeholder="0.00"
    [ngModel]="total"
    #input
    (ngModelChange)="handleOnChange('total', $event, input)"
  />
</mat-form-field>

ts
  public handleOnChange = (field: any, e: any, input: any) => {
    console.log('hell', field);
    this.total = 90;
    input.value = 90;
  };

Stackblitz Demo

Remove (ngModelChange) event
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"class="inputBox"> 
  <input matInput name="total" placeholder="0.00" [ngModel]="total"/>
</mat-form-field>

Now Initialise total's value in constructor so it will remain same until input change
constructor() { 
  this.total=90
}

Now replace [ngModel]="total" with [(ngModel)]="total" and it will automatically assign new value into total and it will reflect in input and add [value]="total" for reflating initial value into input
So final code will be
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"class="inputBox">
  <input matInput name="total" placeholder="0.00" [(ngModel)]="total" [value]="total"/>
</mat-form-field>


but while initial i want the input to be null value only when user types anything in the input I need it to be changed to 90

Then do not assign total in constructor and remove [value]="total" from input
